# Can existing key pair be used if I restart the ec2 instance(stop and start) in aws or do we need to create new key pair or launch another instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssh, putty

I am trying to connect to linux ec2 instance feom windows pc. Firewall is open on port 22. But I am getting Network Timeout while connecting through putty. I have tried to debug, but everything seems fine.
I am able to connect using browser based ssh instance but not using putty or standalone ssh client.
So my only doubt is if I had to create a new key pair because I once restarted the ec2 instance.

Comment: You do not need to create a new keypair when restarting an instance

Comment: More common ssh problems include: logging in as the correct user (ec2-user, ubuntu etc.), private key permissions too open on the host machine (should be 400), and firewalls

Comment: What do you mean by "able to connect using browser based ssh instance"?

Comment: This is not a programming question.

Comment: There is no issue while connecting with Browser Based SSH connection. Issue is with Standlone SSH client .

Comment: I have tried to debug by following https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/TroubleshootingInstancesConnecting.html but everything is fine

Answer (score 1):

No, you don't need to create a new key pair(.pem file) for connecting to your EC2 instance after restarts.

You should be able to connect to the instance through ssh after restart if you nothing has changed such as IP address or Security Group rules.

One of the reason can be that your public IP has changed due to some reason, so check that and connect accordingly.

The public IP associated to the EC2 instance can change in some circumstances. Here is the [official documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-instance-addressing.html#concepts-public-addresses) snippet referring that:

> You cannot manually associate or disassociate a public IP address from
>   your instance. Instead, in certain cases, we release the public IP
>   address from your instance, or assign it a new one:
>
> We release your instance's public IP address when it is stopped or
>   terminated. Your stopped instance receives a new public IP address
>   when it is restarted.
>
> We release your instance's public IP address when you associate an
>   Elastic IP address with it. When you disassociate the Elastic IP
>   address from your instance, it receives a new public IP address.
>
> If the public IP address of your instance in a VPC has been released,
>   it will not receive a new one if there is more than one network
>   interface attached to your instance.
>
> If your instance's public IP address is released while it has a
>   secondary private IP address that is associated with an Elastic IP
>   address, the instance does not receive a new public IP address.

Comment: Yes, after restarting ec2 instance the public dns has changed and i have make sure to connect to newly changed public dns with existing key pair(ppk) from putty. But still I'm getting network timeout.

Comment: However, I am able to connect using browser based ssh client

Comment: Does it have a public DNS/IP address

Comment: Yes it has public dns(IPv4)

Comment: Is there a change in your security group rules or your client IP address?

Comment: No there is no change in security group rules or client IP address

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you do not need to create new key pair to launch your instance. What you need to do are the following:

1. Make sure you are using the correct key pair. You can verify this by going to the AWS console, select your instance, at the data section below, find "Key pair name"
2. Then, check for that public key (pem) file that you used to launch that instance
3. Using PuttyGen, load you pem file and save the generated key as private key (now you have your ppk file
4. Check your instance's Security Group and make you you opened port 22 (SSH) to 0.0.0.0/0
5. Open Putty and paste the following:

   - `Host Name`: Instance's Public IP
   - `Connections > Data > Login Details`: ec2-user (AmazonLinux) ubuntu (Ubuntu)
   - `Connection > SSH > Auth > Private Key`: Choose the generated PPK in step3
   - Click Open
6. You should now be able to open your instance via SSH

Comment: I have followed above steps before posting this question. Since I have followed exact steps as above, I am not sure what went wrong

Comment: I guess you are accessing the instance via SSH using a different private key. I suggest you create a new instance and make sure to keep the correct pem file for that instance.

Comment: No I am using old ppk file only. I have just restarted ec2 instance thereafter. And I'm trying to connect with newly assigned public dns.

Answer (score 0):

It was corporate network issue. Got it resolved. Sorry for inconvenience.

Comment: And that's why was not a programming question in the first place.